# How to open ANYDESK from ROOT USER in UBUNTU?

Tags: 20.04, permissions, kubuntu, xubuntu, anydesk

I tried opening anydesk from root user but it shows following error message (screenshot mentioned below) ? I wonder what is the solutions to solve this problem so that ANYDESK can be open from ROOT USER in UBUNTU?

[image]

Comment: What you're wanting to do is a very unwise (*and that's probably being kind*) thing to do. Whatever you're trying to do would be better handled in other ways. GUI tools should not be run by *root*, but instead run in *user space* wherever possible for security reasons. I suggest you re-evaluate your reason for attempting it.

Comment: Thank you for your input, guiverc. I completely agree that security should be a top priority when dealing with system administration tasks.

The reason for my attempt to run the GUI tool as root is to address a specific issue that requires elevated privileges. However, I understand the potential risks involved in doing so. To mitigate these risks, I plan to take additional precautions, such as limiting the root user's access to only the necessary resources required for the task and ensuring the tool is from a trusted source.

Comment: No need to run Anydesk as root. Use a normal user for GUI access via Anydesk and do root task via `sudo` !!!

Comment: This resembles an [XY question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): Seems like you have some undisclosed problem, but you are instead asking about your proposed solution (Anydesk as Root) instead of the actual problem.